# Marginal probability from probability of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

If we have the probability of sum of two random variables $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y \leq \theta) $$

How can we obtain the marginal probability  of $X$

**My Solution**
I perform marginal probability as follows:

$$\int_y P(X+Y\leq \theta) dy$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: This solution depends on the form of $P$. Is $P$ a function of x and y (2 arguments) or is it a function of just their sum?

Comment: @Bey There is no function of x denoted P here.

Comment: @Tyrone In general one cannot recover the distribution of X from the distribution of X+Y, especially not through the formula you suggest. Any hypothesis on the stochastic dependence of (X,Y)?

Comment: @Did I was referring to the probability...does the op have the joint probability or just the probability of the sum.